# AngularJ/ng-resource + Nodejs/express.js querystring compatibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angularjs-ng-resource

I'm working on a SPA built with AngularJS+ng-resource that works with RestAPI built with Node.js+Express.js+Sequelize.

The problem: express.js accepts and parse **queryString as Json Object**. Ng-resource produces a bad queryString if you use this json object as parameters.

This is the angularJS ng-resource RestAPI call:

```
var queryString = {include: [{model: 'player', attributes: ['name','surname']}], where: {club: 32} };

Contract.query(queryString,
    function(data) {
        vm.club_players = data;
    }
);
```

That should be produce something like this:

```
include[1][attributes][]:surname&
include[1][attributes][]:name&
include[1][model]:player&
where[club]:32
```

Actually it works if use this queryString instead the plain json object:

```
var queryString = {'where[id_club]': id_club, 'include[1][model]':'real_player', 'include[1][attributes][]':'id', 'include[1][attributes][]':'name', 'include[1][attributes][]':'surname'};
```